# Do Active Directory and the built-in Windows VPN require CALs?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, vpn, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

We are thinking using the built-in Windows Server VPN and use Active Directory to authenticate users.  Do we need CALs to be in compliance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that you have enough user cal's for the number of users you have, you are in compliance. You can check this by checking licensing under server manager.

Comment: So do we need a CAL for each user in AD?

Comment: @phsr - Either enough for each user, or for each machine depending on how you set up your licensing.

Comment: @phsr - Users in terms of User CALs relate to human beings; if you create a user account for a service to use, or create a second account for the same person, then you don't need another CAL.  I use our payroll for CAL compliance.